# How do I select all cells (td and th) in a column based on what radiobutton I select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

An example of what I have in HTML:

```
<table id="testME">
   <tr>
      <td><input id="first" name="choices" type="radio" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="second" name="choices" type="radio" value="2"></td>
      <td><input id="third" name="choices" type="radio" value="3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><label for="first">My first selection</label></td>
      <td><label for="second">My second selection</label></td>
      <td><label for="third">My third selection</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input id="myWords" type="text" /></td>
      <td><select id="mySelects">
             <option value="30">Choice 1</option>
             <option value="31">Choice 2</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td><input id="multiOne" name="multiSelect" type="checkbox" value="one" />
          <label for="multiOne">One</label><br />
          <input id="multiTwo" name="multiSelect" type="checkbox" value="two" />
          <label for="multiTwo">Two</label><br />
          <input id="multiThree" name="multiSelect" type="checkbox" value="three" />
          <label for="multiThree">Three</label><br />
          <input id="multiFour" name="multiSelect" type="checkbox" value="four" />
          <label for="multiFour">Four</label><br />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to happen is when I click on the radiobutton or its label, all of the cells in that column (whether it's th or td) become highlighted a certain color. I'd like to do this with JQuery.

What I researching before I posted this question:

```
<script>
function highlightSelection() {
        $('#testME > tr > td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'gray');
    }
</script>
<input id="jquerytest" type="button" onclick="javascript:highlightSelection();" value="Change Color" />@:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Perhaps you can show what you've done and someone can help you make it work?

Comment: @dotnetN00b did you even look at my answer? :-P

Comment: @Neal: Yes, I am. But I was responding to the two posters. They definitely had a legitimate point and I should have posted my attempt when I posted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("table").on("click", "input", function() {
    var td = $(this).parent("td"),
        tdIndex = td.index();
    var tr = td.parent("tr"),
        trIndex = tr.index();

    $("table, table tr, table tr td").css("background", "none");

    $("td:eq(" + tdIndex + ")", "tr").css("background", "red");
    $("tr:eq(" + trIndex + ")").css("background", "blue");

});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rZqdP/

Comment: Oddly, I keep getting an `Object doesn't support this method or property` error. I'm using MVC 3 and Razor. I've tried it by myself and inside `$(document).ready()` and when that didn't work `jQuery(document).ready()`

Comment: I changed the `on` method to `$('table input').click(function () {....` and it worked just fine. Thanks, @Neal

Comment: When I used `on` I kept getting the error in my first comment. The `click` method made that error go away. I'm using JQuery 1.5.1 at the moment.

Comment: @dotnetN00b well that makes sense. `.on(...)` only exists in jQuery > 1.7. switch over and you will be good :-)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I thought it was always a wrapper for `on`. Learn something new every day. Thanks!